# R bin data by unique ID

Tags: r, dataframe, binning

From a data.frame:

<kbd>RowColFovCellID 1</kbd><kbd>Feret</kbd>
<kbd>001001000</kbd>      <kbd>1.1</kbd>      
<kbd>001002000</kbd>      <kbd>0.3</kbd>      
<kbd>001002000</kbd>      <kbd>0.2</kbd>      
<kbd>001003000</kbd>      <kbd>1.5</kbd>      
<kbd>001001000</kbd>      <kbd>3.4</kbd>      
<kbd>001002000</kbd>      <kbd>2.4</kbd>      
<kbd>003003001</kbd>      <kbd>0.7</kbd>      
<kbd>001001000</kbd>      <kbd>3.6</kbd>

I would like to bin data by a unique ID and show the results as new columns in a dataframe, for example:

<kbd>RowColFovCellID</kbd><kbd>0-1</kbd><kbd>1-2</kbd><kbd>2-3</kbd><kbd>3-4</kbd><kbd>4-5</kbd>
<kbd>001001000</kbd>      <kbd>0</kbd>      <kbd>1</kbd>      <kbd>0</kbd>      <kbd>2</kbd>      <kbd>0</kbd>      
<kbd>001002000</kbd>      <kbd>2</kbd>      <kbd>0</kbd>      <kbd>1</kbd>      <kbd>0</kbd>      <kbd>0</kbd>      
<kbd>001003000</kbd>      <kbd>0</kbd>      <kbd>1</kbd>      <kbd>0</kbd>      <kbd>0</kbd>      <kbd>0</kbd>      
<kbd>003003001</kbd>      <kbd>1</kbd>      <kbd>0</kbd>      <kbd>0</kbd>      <kbd>0</kbd>      <kbd>0</kbd>

I have tried using ddply and cut but not managed it so far.

Thanks

Comment: Regarding binning, what was wrong with [@Martín Bel's `cut` answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851362/r-binning-dataset-and-surface-plot/20851667#20851667) to one of your previous question about binning on similar data?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you take a two-step approach to accomplish what you are aiming to do. First, create an additional column in your data.frame in which you classify the observed values in the variable 'Feret'. Then second, you use `xtable` from the `xtable package` to create the cross table you show above.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you tried `cut`, but don't show what you tried.

This seems to be a straightforward `table` problem. Assuming your `data.frame` is called "mydf" and your columns are "RowColFovCellID" and "Feret", try:

```
table(mydf$RowColFovCellID, cut(mydf$Feret, 0:5))
# 
#         (0,1] (1,2] (2,3] (3,4] (4,5]
# 1001000     0     1     0     2     0
# 1002000     2     0     1     0     0
# 1003000     0     1     0     0     0
# 3003001     1     0     0     0     0
```